# How to test with Jest and Enzyme a custom form hook?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm new doing automation testing, so I'm trying to do some unit tests, I built a usual custom hook to handle the form events and the inputs changes.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const useFormHook = (callback) => {

    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        if (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
        }
        setInputs({})
        callback();
      }

    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
         e.persist();
         setInputs(inputs => ( {...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value } ));
    }

    return{
       handleSubmit,
       handleInputChange,
       inputs
    }
}

export default useFormHook
```

and the implementation goes in to a search bar, which event will update a context state, and looks like this:

```
const SearchBar = () => {

    const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

    useAsyncHook(search); // I'm using an async custom hook to fetch some data with axios. 

    const handleFormSubmit = () => {
        
             let targetValue = Object.values(inputs).join().toLowerCase()

             setSearch(targetValue)
                         
             document.forms[0].reset()
    }

    const { inputs, handleSubmit, handleInputChange } = useCustomFormHook(handleFormSubmit)

     return (
        
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="searchForm">
             <input 
                id='searchBar'
                type="text" 
                name="value" 
                value={inputs.value || ''}
                onChange={handleInputChange} 
                required
                className={`input`}
             />
            <input 
               className={`button primary`} 
               type="submit" 
               value=" Search" 
               id='search-button'
            /> 
        
       </form>
       
    )
}
```

till now this work fine..:

```
import React from "react";
import { mount, shallow } from "enzyme";
//components and hooks
import useFormHook from "../../../Services/Hooks/customFormHook";
//import useAsyncHook from "../../../Services/Hooks/customAsyncHook";
//import SeachBar from "../SearchBar";

describe("Custom hooks suite test", () => {
  // const wrapper = shallow(<SeachBar />);

  let results;

  const handleHookTester = (hook) => {
    function HookWrapper() {
      results = hook();
      return null;
    }
    mount(<HookWrapper />);
    return results;
  };

  it("Form hook test", () => {
    handleHookTester(useFormHook);
    expect(results.inputs).toStrictEqual({});
  });
});
```

So far I've managed to make it work, but this is just the customFormHook and I'd like to test  and my customAsyncHook which looks like this:

```
const useAsyncHook = (id) => {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState('false');

    const { findData } = useContext(AppContext) 
// 1 -  
     useEffect(() => {
    
      async function getData() {
     
        try {
           setLoading('true'); 
          
           const response = await axios(
             `someEndPoint/${id}`
           );

           findData({type:FIND_DATA, data:response.data }); 

        } catch (error) {
          
           setLoading('null'); 
           findData({type:FIND_DATA, data:null }); 
        }

      }
       
      if (id !== "") {
         getData();
      }

    }, [id]);
     
    return  loading; 

  }
```

and if I try something like `const wrapper = shallow(<SearchBar/>)` or:
`handleHookTester(useAsyncHook);` the test fails throwing the following error:

```
 ● Custom hooks suite test › encountered a declaration exception

    TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'findData' of '(0 , _react.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.

       8 |     const [loading, setLoading] = useState('false');
       9 | 
    > 10 |     const { findData } = useContext(AppContext) 
         |             ^
      11 | // 1 -  
      12 |      useEffect(() => {
```

So the question is should I mock that function? and how?

Comment: Mock useCustomHook and handleInputChange. Simulate onChange of search. Check whether the mocked handleInputChange is being called. same for submit methd also

Comment: Ok, there is a problem, in <SearchBar/> I use a custom hook to call an api... in this hook I use a `const { findData } = useContext(AppContext)` so the test throws the following error: 
`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'findData' of '(0 , _react.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.

 > 10 |     const { findData } = useContext(AppContext) //action to dispatch ..
         |                 ^   `

Comment: You have to mock AppContext also @Santiago Spinetto Jung